# Get lists with a custome item

Tags: mongodb, laravel, lumen

I have a list with items `(id,vehicle_type_id,center_share)` in center_share collection and when i got all lists, vehicle_type return and put in each list ,vehicle_type returned by vehicle_type_id form vehicle_type collection

default list is :

```
{
 "data": [
 {
  "_id": "56ef4450c265ad109c5392c5",
  "vehicle_type_id": "56ef1f1dc265ad109c5392b8",
  "center_share": 2323,
  "setting_type": "center_share"
 },
 {
  "_id": "56ef447ec265ad109c5392c6",
  "vehicle_type_id": "56ef21b3c265ad109c5392ba",
  "center_share": 2222,
  "setting_type": "center_share"
 },
]
```

i want to be :

```
{
 "data": [
 {
  "_id": "56ef4450c265ad109c5392c5",
  "vehicle_type_id": "56ef1f1dc265ad109c5392b8",
  "center_share": 2323,
  "setting_type": "center_share",
  "vehicle_type": "car",
 },
 {
  "_id": "56ef447ec265ad109c5392c6",
  "vehicle_type_id": "56ef21b3c265ad109c5392ba",
  "center_share": 2222,
  "setting_type": "center_share",
  "vehicle_type": "moto",
 },
]
```

Comment: please help me friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine data from two collections you can use Left-outer Join (Available from version 3.2).

Use below link for example, https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup